# Getting the default SQL Server directory in VB.Net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I guess the default path for the SQL Server files is located at:

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA*

Is there any way of reading the default directory with the .NET Framework?

Comment: Which is a more generic way of asking "why do you need to know?"

Comment: Are you asking how to find the default or how to read the files?

Comment: @ SLaks: I am trying to find the default one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get you the installation folder (ie. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL`) for the SQL Server that you specify in the connection string:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "whatever..."
Dim serverConnection As New ServerConnection(connection)
Dim server As New Server(serverConnection)
Dim installationDirectory As String = server.Information.RootDirectory
```

These classes are all part of [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

The MSDN docs for RootDirectory can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.information.rootdirectory.aspx). Specifying the correct SQL Server instance in the connection string supplied to the `ServerConnection` will ensure you get the directory for the correct instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can read files and directories using the shared methods of the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) and [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) classes.

You can find the path of a specific database by running the following SQL:  `SELECT Filename FROM Sysdatabases WHERE name = 'MyDB'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Obtain-your-SQL-Server-s-database-location/0,339028455,320283099,00.htm):

> The value's actual registry location
>   will depend upon your setup and the
>   versions of SQL that you have
>   installed. The tag you're looking for
>   is SQLDataRoot. On my machine, it's
>   located in the following node:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Setup
```

So you can just loop through the registry using [.Net library](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WindowsRegistry04262005045814AM/WindowsRegistry.aspx), obtain the relevant key, probe into it, obtain further keys until you hit the correct keys and the correct values.

Comment: It will also vary if you have multiple instances on the same machine.